# Rqueue Completed Jobs

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I am facing an issue when trying to enqueue a huge amount of messages with rqueue. My concern is that even though all jobs are processed successfuly, they are not discarded from redis (I suppose they will be discared based their ttl). My main problem is that as data are increasing the process becomes slower. I suppose since I want to enqueue around 300k messages, all these jobs will wait to be discarded when ttl finished. Is there any option to discard these jobs after their completion without waiting this ttl, or speedup the clean up mechanism?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey are you using https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue ?